# Accesing a class instance from another classes instance (calling methods)

Tags: java

So my program consists of two classes
1. My main class handling GUI which extends JFrame so I need to instance it to configure my JFrame . 
2. MyClass which requests and processes data requested from server using an API which has to have an instance of an API class which handles requests in addition . (its a runnable class and implents a wrapper from API)

So if I simply instance MyClass like (Runnable Processor = new MyClass()), inside my main class and create a thread with it and run . I cant access methods of MyClass or API class methods (i am specifically interested in a connection killer method). Im trying to access it like Processor.API.eDisconnect(). That doesnt work.

But if do it  like so : Create an Arraylist of MyClass then add an instance of MyClass to the list . Create a thread like Thread myThread = new Thread(List.get(0)) . I can access my methods of API class like List.get(0).API.eDisconnect().

So why does the second method work ? the only difference that the class instance is an independent variable or is in a list .

Is it proper practice what problems can occur ? is there a better way to do it ?

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package basket;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

/**
 *
 * @author ivan
 */
public class Basket extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
    protected List<TwsHandler> TWS = new ArrayList<>();
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
       Basket main = new Basket();
       main.Launch();
    }
    public void Launch()
    {
        TWS.add(new TwsHandler());
        BorderLayout MainLayout = new BorderLayout();
        JButton Start = new JButton("Start");
        Start.addActionListener(this);
        Start.setActionCommand("Start");
        JButton Stop = new JButton("Stop");
        Stop.addActionListener(this);
        Stop.setActionCommand("Stop");
        this.setLayout(MainLayout);
        this.add(Start , BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        this.add(Stop , BorderLayout.WEST);
        this.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter()
        {
            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e){System.exit(0);}
        });
        this.setTitle("Option basket robot");
        this.setBounds(100, 100, 800, 600);
        this.setVisible(true);

    }
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
    {
        switch (e.getActionCommand()) {
            case "Start":
                Thread Processor = new Thread(TWS.get(0));
                Processor.start();
                break;
            case "Stop":
                System.out.println(TWS.get(0).Eclient.isConnected());
                break;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Show code of `main` please.

Comment: Can you show us what doesn't work, and explain what you mean but that?

Comment: Please learn Java naming conventions, and stick to them. Variables start with a lower-case letter.

Comment: It is hard for me to understand what you are asking. It would help if you posted a short, self contained, compilable example (see http://sscce.org/) of a program that works and a program that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only difference is that in the first case, you're referencing a `MyClass` instance as a `Runnable`, whereas in the second case, you're referencing it as a `MyClass` (through an `ArrayList`, which doesn't serve any purpose).

Instead of

```
Runnable processor = new MyClass();
```

use

```
MyClass processor = new MyClass();
```

since you want to be able to call `MyClass` methods.

Comment: Thanks , I never thought that would change the so much .